# Typescript: Get properties of extending class from parent class

Tags: typescript, inheritance, reflection, abstract-class

How can I get properties of a child class in an abstract class's method?

```js
abstract class Parent {
  id: string;

  logProps() {
    // HOW can I log all properties of a child class
    // and their values? For example, the name.
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  name: string;

  constructor(name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
  }
}

const child = new Child("Daniel");
child.logProps();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved your code a bit, the thing what you missed was the lack of a `super()`, this states that the child class inherrits all the properties from its parent class. Also the attributes in the parrent class need to be marked as abstract, or they need to be implemented in the parrent class.

```
abstract class Parent {
abstract id: string;

 abstract logProps(): Parent; // make abstract or implement here
}

class Child extends Parent {
    id: string;
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
       super();
       this.id = ""//some initial value
       this.name = name;
  }

    logProps(): Parent {
       return this;
    }
} 

const child = new Child("Daniel");
child.logProps();
```

I have chosen to make all properties abstract, you might also remove the `abstract` keyword and implement the method in the parent class.

**EDIT**

I have another implementation, you can define the method in the parrent class and simply log `this`, this will contain all properties.

```
abstract class Parent {

id: string = "DEFAULT VALUE";

logProps() {
    console.log(this); // Using this, this contains all properties
 }
}

class Child extends Parent {

name: string;

constructor(name: string) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
 }
}

const child = new Child("Daniel");
child.logProps();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
abstract class Parent {
  constructor(public id?: string) {}
  logProps() {
      console.log(Object.keys(this));
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {    
  constructor(public id?: string, public name?: string) {
    super(id);
  }
}

const child = Child('01', "Daniel");
child.logProps();
```

Comment: You should try to explain a little on how this solved the question of the OP.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.